# Why can I not get a reference to my component from the ReactDOM.render() callback?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs, react-dom

I have the following code:

```
const priceCalculator = ReactDOM.render(<PriceCalculator />, reactHolder);
```

I need to use `priceCalculator` later in my code but ESLint is complaining that I shouldn't use the return value of `ReactDOM.render()`. That's when I discovered that you can [pass a 3rd argument](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/no-render-return-value.md) to `ReactDOM.render()` which is a callback. Great I thought...

```
ReactDOM.render(<PriceCalculator />, reactHolder, function(priceCalculator) {
    // do something with priceCalculator
});
```

But `priceCalculator` is undefined. In the debugger I pause on exceptions and find that `this` is set to my React Component when I'm inside this function. So I rewrite it...

```
ReactDOM.render(<PriceCalculator />, reactHolder, function() {
    const priceCalculator = this;
    // do something with priceCalculator
});
```

It's still undefined. What's going on?

I'm using Webpack to compile es6 React code (using babel).

Comment: `ReactDOM.render` renders the given component into the given DOM element. I believe the callback is invoked on completion of the render. Perhaps what you want is to just do `const priceCalculator = <PriceCalculator />`?

Comment: @sdgluck that's what I did first and it works fine. However this way is discouraged because eventually ReactDOM.render might not return anything https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/no-render-return-value.md

Comment: But the approach I suggested doesn't use `ReactDOM.render` so these details don't apply here?

Comment: The callback seems to work fine in a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/64439/

Comment: Perhaps you could expand on `"I need to use priceCalculator later in my code"` as it is a bit unclear. What do you need it for?

Comment: @sdgluck I mis-read your answer...didn't notice you didn't use render. I need a reference to the particular instance of my component because I am attaching listeners to existing (non-react) DOM nodes. These listeners need to call methods of my component instance.

Comment: @pawel indeed it does. I'm wondering if it's going wrong during the babel > react > webpack processing. If I use the keyword `this` within the function it literally gets changed to `undefined` when the code is compiled. It doesn't just reference `undefined` it has been transpiled to the keyword `undefined`.

Comment: @MrMisterMan are you sure you pass a `function(){}`, not an arrow function like `() => {}`? Because then the lexical scoping of `this`  could result in code with `this` transpiled to `undefined` [babel repl example](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=false&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Cstage-2&code=foo(%20()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20const%20x%20%3D%20this%3B%0A%7D)%3B%0A%0Afoo(%20function()%7B%0A%20%20const%20x%20%3D%20this%3B%0A%7D)%3B)

Comment: @pawel I've tried it both ways. Same result.

Comment: Hacky workaround (or not?) might be to pass some fn as a prop to the component and call it with ref to the DOM node from within the component.

Comment: Example: https://jsfiddle.net/2zbxats7/1/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the [ESLint docs page](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/no-render-return-value.md) you linked it says to use a [callback ref](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html#the-ref-callback-attribute):

> ReactDOM.render() currently returns a reference to the root ReactComponent instance. However, using this return value is legacy and should be avoided because future versions of React may render components asynchronously in some cases. **If you need a reference to the root ReactComponent instance, the preferred solution is to attach a [callback ref](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html#the-ref-callback-attribute) to the root element.**
>
> Source: [React Top-Level API documentation](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#reactdom.render)

So you can pass a callback to the root component via a prop and call this with reference to the component's root node from within its `render` method, via the root node's `ref` prop.

For example ([working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2zbxats7/1/)):

```
class Hello extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <div ref={(node) => this.props.cb(node)}>
        Hello {this.state.name}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

let node

ReactDOM.render(<Hello cb={(n) => node = n} />, ...);

console.log(node)
```

Note: this approach is naive as `ReactDOM.render` may not always render synchronously, in which case the `console.log` statement would print `"undefined"`. (See the above quote: "future versions of React may render components asynchronously in some cases".)

Comment: I tweaked your fiddle to be more like what I'm trying to achieve https://jsfiddle.net/n92sm5f3/1/ It does work (great!) but I still don't understand why the other way does not. The docs page I linked to also says `ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.body, doSomethingWithInst);` should work.

Comment: Yes it is confusing. Perhaps that functionality is no longer available and the docs are out of date - have you tested using an older v. of React? Either way, this is the recommended approach. :-)